# Which approach is better when using Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm facing following problem:

I wan't to keep track of tasks given to users and I want to store this state in Redis.

I can do:

1) create list called "dispatched_tasks" holding many objects (username, task)

2) create many (potentialy thousands) lists called dispatched_tasks:username holding usually few objects (task)

Which approach is better? If I only thought of my comfort, I would choose the second one, as from time to time I will have to search for particular user tasks, and this second approach gives this for free.

But how about Redis? Which approach will be more performant?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis supports different kinds of data structures as shown [here](https://redis.io/topics/data-types). There are different approaches you can take:

Scenario 1:

Using a list data type, your list will contain all the task/user combination for your problem. However, accessing and deleting a task runs in O(n) time complexity (it has to traverse the list to get to the element). This can have an impact in performance if your user has a lot of tasks.

Using sets: 
Similar to lists, but you can add/delete/check for existence in O(1) and sets elements are unique. So if you add another username/task that already exists, it won't add it.

Scenario 2:

The data types do not change. The only difference is that there will be a lot more keys in redis, which in can increase the memory footprint.

From the [FAQ](https://redis.io/topics/faq):

> **What is the maximum number of keys a single Redis instance can hold? and what the max number of elements in a Hash, List, Set, Sorted
>   Set?**
>
> Redis can handle up to 232 keys, and was tested in practice to handle
>   at least 250 million keys per instance.
>
> Every hash, list, set, and sorted set, can hold 232 elements.
>
> In other words your limit is likely the available memory in your
>   system.
>
> **What's the Redis memory footprint?**
>
> To give you a few examples (all obtained using 64-bit instances):
>
> An empty instance uses ~ 3MB of memory.
>  1 Million small Keys ->
>   String Value pairs use ~ 85MB of memory.
>  1 Million Keys -> Hash
>   value, representing an object with 5 fields, use ~ 160 MB of
>   memory.
>  To test your use case is trivial using the
>   redis-benchmark utility to generate random data sets and check with
>   the INFO memory command the space used.